# TableRowController draw bug?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, watchos-2

What I'm trying to do now is a table, with 2 labels on a row, and different background color for each label. I stumbled upon something very unexpected.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image: This is what I want to achieve]
[image: This is the structure]

But once I do the same thing inside a tableRowController I get this:
 
[image: Result using TableRowController]
[image]

The proprieties of the objects are the same, and yet, the groups inside the table do not extend to the whole view. It's like they hit an invisible wall or something.

- Does anyone else has the same issue?
- Is there a fix/workaround for this?

P.S. I messed around with all the proprieties in attribute inspector I could, was not able to get to the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top-level group, set "Insets" to "Custom", with 0 values for all of them. You'll probably need to add back insets on the lower-level groups.

Comment: Well it did work, thank you, but I still don't get why the initial problem, cause default value for insets was 0.

Comment: No, it was 0 once you set it to custom. Default values are different.